# SagePay - How do you pass company name field to sagepay form?

Tags: woocommerce, opayo

we have recently moved over to a new website using woocommerce. We are trying to find out how to pass the company name to sage pay so when we import it into sage 50 accounts it finds the correct company to match the account to.
Currently it is creating a new company using the first and last name of the person as there is no where (it appears) for sagepay to allow this info.
How do we do this please?

Answer (score 0):

The email address is used as the identifier at the moment, so if your Sage 50 records have the correct email address, and this is supplied with the transaction registration, it *should* match up.